# Finding correct path to files in subfolders with os.walk with python?

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to create a program that copies files with certain file extension to the given folder. When files are located in subfolders instead of the root folder the program fails to get correct path. In its current state the program works perfectly for the files in the root folder, but it crashes when it finds matching items in subfolders. The program tries to use rootfolder as directory instead of the correct subfolder.

My code is as follows

```
# Selective_copy.py walks through file tree and copies files with
# certain extension to give folder
import shutil
import os
import re

# Deciding the folders and extensions to be targeted
# TODO: user input instead of static values
extension = "zip"
source_folder = "/Users/viliheikkila/documents/kooditreeni/"
destination_folder = "/Users/viliheikkila/documents/test"

def Selective_copy(source_folder):
    # create regex to identify file extensions
    mo = re.compile(r"(\w+).(\w+)")  # Group(2) represents the file extension
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source_folder):
        for i in filenames:
            if mo.search(i).group(2) == extension:
                file_path = os.path.abspath(i)
                print("Copying from " + file_path + " to " + destination_folder)
                shutil.copy(file_path, destination_folder)

Selective_copy(source_folder)
```

Comment: Thanks in advance for everyone!

Comment: Please provide details about these "crashes".

Comment: The first thing I notice is you did not escape the . in your regex... Please remember that . matches EVERYTHING in regular expressions. If you want to match only the actually period character `.`, then you need to escape it with a `\ `like so: `\.`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder Nadia. I actually tried using the escape with the regex and the code does not work at all when I do that. In its current state the regex seems to work.

Comment: Scott, I get error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/viliheikkila/Documents/Kooditreeni/bacon.zip'
Vilis-MBP:kooditreeni viliheikkila$

This is due the fact that there indeed is no file called bacon.zip the root folder, since it is actually in a subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

`dirpath` is one of the things provided by `walk` for a reason: it gives the path to the directory that the items in `files` is located in.  You can use that to determine the subfolder you should be using.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I managed to fix the code. As Łukasz below stated the file_path was wrong. I changed it to `file_path = dirpath + "/" + i` and now the code runs like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_path = os.path.abspath(i)
```

This line is blatantly wrong.
Keep in mind that `filenames` keeps list of base file names. At this point it's just a list of strings and (technically) they are not associated at all with files in filesystem.

[`os.path.abspath` does string-only operations and attempts to merge file name with current working dir](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath). As a result, merged filename points to file that **does not exist**.

What should be done is merge between `root` and base file name (both values yield from `os.walk`):

```
file_path = os.path.abspath(dirpath, i)
```

Comment: Thanks Łukasz! I changed  file_path and the code works fine now. I used `file_path = dirpath + "/" + i` and it works great